# Visual Studio 2015 IDE breaking for no reason

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I run this code, my IDE is breaking (no specific error just this Windows messages that says Programm doesn't work anymore).

Could you check if it is due to my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i; int array1[10], array2[10];

    for (i = 0; 1 < 10; i++) {
        array1[i] = i;
        array2[i] = i;
    }

    array2[9] = 30;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        if (array1[i] == array2[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            printf("Die Arrays unterscheiden sich an Position %d\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger. Step through the code line by line.

Comment: Yes! it's due to the code, but' it's very easy! look carefully

Comment: Compile with warnings enables. It should say something like "comparison is always true"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I assume it is your code.

`1 < 10` is always `true`. So `for (i = 0; 1 < 10; i++) {...}` runs forever.

I imagine what you meant to do was more like...

`for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {...}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11082898)

Comment: @Bono, I appreciate your thoughts; however, it does "answer" the question. While I might not be well versed in the current VC++ behavior, I know that such an error will cause catastrophic failure. That's pretty clear, I think, by the code OP posted; have a look please.

Comment: Then might I suggest you give a solution to the problem?

Comment: @Bono, done. That's the best I can do given what's provided in the question. If you're the down voter, please consider revising your judgement.

Comment: This is the right answer. It's trivial enough that whoever looks at it will know how to fix it, so I don't think the fact it's short is so bad.